# React SPFX - How to check whether or not a user is a member of a specific Azure Directory

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, spfx

As the title suggests, I am trying to find out whether or not a specific user from my ad group is part of another ad group.
There are plenty of questions that ask the same question but the context of the question differs a lot.

I have read some documentation about on this problem but nothing related on how to get users or groups from your Azure Directory.

For now I am just trying to log out an Azure Directory group or user inside my `getFAQ()` method. I cannot retrieve some data from my Azure Directory

If someone have an idea on how to accomplish this or could point me in the right direction, it would greatly appreciated.

My provider class looks like this. I have a property called `_sp: SPFI` that I initialize inside my constructor `this._sp = spfi().using(SPFx(context));`

A sample of my provider class where I would like to retrieve the data inside my `getFAQ()` method.

```
export class FAQProvider implements IFAQProvider {
    private _sp: SPFI;
    private faqListId: string;

    constructor(context: WebPartContext, faqListId: string) {
        this._sp = spfi().using(SPFx(context));
        this.faqListId = faqListId;
    }


    public async getFAQ(): Promise<IFAQ[]> {
        let result: IFAQ[] = await this._sp.web.lists.getById(this.faqListId).items.expand("FAQ_Category", "FAQ_SubCategory").select("*", "FAQ_Category/Title", "FAQ_SubCategory/Title", "FAQ_Category/CategoryColor", "FAQ_SubCategory/SubCategoryColor")();

        let resultFiltered: IFAQ[] = result.map(x => ({
            Answer: x.Answer,
            FAQ_CategoryId: x.FAQ_CategoryId,
            FAQ_SubCategoryId: x.FAQ_SubCategoryId,
            Question: x.Question,
            FAQ_Category: x.FAQ_Category,
            FAQ_SubCategory: x.FAQ_SubCategory,
            ID: x.ID,
            Audience_Target: x.Audience_Target,
            Audience_TargetId: x.Audience_TargetId,
        }));
        const memberGroup = await this._sp.web.associatedMemberGroup();

        console.log(memberGroup);

        return resultFiltered;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transitiveMemberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-and-odata-cast-to-get-transitive-membership-in-groups-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects) method on users from Your member group.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by on "users from Your member group"? As far as I know the ```_sp``` property is only for the SharePoint users or groups and not a way to access the Azure Directory.

Comment: Sure, I understand You are using pnp, here is how You can communicate with MS Graph API using PnPJS
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/graph/docs/
I assumed You want to check if members of associated member group are members of other AAD group (this is why You use this._sp.web.associatedMemberGroup(), but if that's not the case - just use transitiveMemberOf method on any user and You will know which AAD group he is a member of.
And yes, You are correct, _sp can get You only SharePoint groups - for AAD groups You have to use MS Graph API.